why is there a braces behind NewDocumentCommand{\printseq}?
The macros is from Is it possible to set a particular item of a LaTeX3 seq?. I'm not very clear the effect of {} in \NewDocumentCommand{\printseq}{}. Is {} identical to {o} ?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \my_seq

\seq_set_split:Nnn \my_seq {;} {a;;b;c;d}

\NewDocumentCommand {\printseq}{} % the braces here cannot be removed , but can be replaced by {o}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \my_seq {,~}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Sequence: \printseq

\end{document}




The argument denotes the arguments of the commands being defined. This command has no arguments, so the list is empty.

thanks @David Carlisle . I confused newcommand with NewDocumentCommand . If I use \newcommand {\printseq}{\seq_use:Nn \g_tmp_seq {,\ ~}} , then it is unnecessary to use empty list.

@xcn the syntax is different but the same issue with \newcommand with \newcommand you specify the argument form by for example [3] but if there are no arguments you do not need that option. \NewDocumentCommand takes a list of argument types not simply a number so needed a different syntax

yes, do you think is it a good habit to use '\newcommand' instead when there is no option ?

It's not the same \NewDocumentCommand makes a protected command.  try \newcommand\foo{hello}\typeout{\foo}   then the same with \NewDocumentCommand

\NewDocumentCommand {\printseq}{} % the braces here cannot be removed , but can be replaced by {o}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \my_seq {,~}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand takes three arguments:

the name of the command i.e. \printseq
an argument specification (possibly empty) i.e. {}
the definition of the command i.e. \seq_use:Nn \my_seq {,~}

While you could replace {} with {o}, doing so wouldn't be good practice because o indicates an optional argument, which the command does nothing with. So if a user writes
\printseq [this is my sequence]

\printseq will silently eat [this is my sequence], which will disappear for no apparent reason.
Note that you could also replace {} with any number of other things:

{s}
{s+o t{+} sO{Cats!} d()}

However, this would not be a good idea for just the same reason: the definition would do nothing with any arguments except silently eat them.

thanks @cfr for detailed explaination. I did't notice empty argument case before.
